# pandas push data to mysql with index column

Tags: mysql, pandas, indexing

I am using python pandas with a mysql database. Initally it worked fine but recently as the table gets larger, the query get slower and slower.

I have read that using index on columns can increase the performance a lot. I am not familiar with index, especially when working with pandas.

Currently I am using pandas.DataFrame.to_sql to push a dataframe to database. I noticed there is an argument about the index in that method but not sure if that is what I am looking for. The column I would like to index is date which non-unique. Thanks for any suggestions!

Bo

Comment: Try utilizing the `chunksize` parameter which controls the number of rows to be written to the database at one time.

Comment: It is OK, and very often a good idea, to index non-unique columns.  And it can be good to have a "composite" index -- two columns in an index.

Comment: Indexing does _not_ speed up `INSERTs`.  It slows it down _a little_; in return, it greatly speeds up _some_ `SELECTs`.